# XeLaTeX compiles too slow

Tags: xetex, pstricks, compiling, font-encodings, auto-pst-pdf

See `poker` package [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-poker?lang=en).

This is the slowest stage.
[image]
It takes about 2 minutes to compile... to go from[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D327C.png) to [3] and etc

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-poker}


%\usepackage[top=0cm,bottom=0cm,left=3cm,right=3cm]{geometry}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{comicsansl}


\title{Poker hands from highest to lowest}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\psset{unit=1.1,crdshadow=none,index=jumbo}

%\maketitle


\section{Royal flush}
$A, K, Q, J, 10$, all the same suit.
    \begin{center}
        \crdAd \crdKd \crdQd \crdJd \crdtend
    \end{center}


\section{Straight flush}
Five cards in a sequence, all in the same suit.
    \begin{center}
        \crdJc \crdtenc \crdninec \crdeigc \crdsevc
    \end{center}


\section{Four of a kind}
All four cards of the same rank.
    \begin{center}
        \crdJc \crdJh \crdJs \crdJd \crdsevd
    \end{center}


\section{Full house}
Three of a kind with a pair.
    \begin{center}
        \crdtens
        \crdtenh
        \crdtend
        \crdnines
        \crdnined
    \end{center}


\section{Flush}
Any five cards of the same suit, but not in a sequence.
    \begin{center}
        \crdfours
        \crdJs
        \crdeigs
        \crdtwos
        \crdnines
    \end{center}


\section{Straight}
Five cards in a sequence, but not of the same suit.
    \begin{center}
        \crdninec
        \crdeigd
        \crdsevc
        \crdsixd
        \crdfiveh
    \end{center}



\section{Three of a kind}
Three cards of the same rank.
    \begin{center}
        \crdsevc
        \crdsevd
        \crdsevs
        \crdKs
        \crdtred
    \end{center}



\section{Two pair}
Two different pairs.
    \begin{center}
        \crdfourc
        \crdfours
        \crdtres
        \crdtred
        \crdQs
    \end{center}

\section{Pair}
Two cards of the same rank.
    \begin{center}
        \crdAd
        \crdAs
        \crdeigc
        \crdfours
        \crdsevh
    \end{center}

\section{High Card}
When you haven't made any of the hands above, the highest card plays. \\
In the example below, the jack plays as the highest card.
    \begin{center}
        \crdtred
        \crdJs
        \crdeigc
        \crdfourh
        \crdtwos
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

Console output:

```
Command Line:   xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "make2.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\cy.i\Google Drive\Temp\Poker

xelatex: warning: running with administrator privileges
initexmf: warning: Option --admin should be specified when running this program with administrative privileges
initexmf: warning: Option --admin should be specified when running this program with administrative privileges
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (MiKTeX 2.9.6745 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(make2.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pst-plot\pst-plot.sty
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pstricks\pstricks.sty"
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\iftex\iftex.sty)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\shellesc.sty")
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\xetex.def"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\pst-xkey.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex")))))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\pstricks.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\pst-fp.tex"
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-com
mon.tex
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-com
mon-lists.tex))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.cod
e.tex
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfilt
ered.code.tex))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code
.tex
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex

(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code
.tex
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code
.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.co
de.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.code.tex
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.basic.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.trigonometric.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.random.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.comparison.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.base.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.round.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.misc.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.cod
e.tex)))
`PSTricks' v2.84  <2018/05/01> (tvz,hv)

(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-pstricks\pstricks.c
on ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\xdvipdfmx.cfg"))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-pstricks\pstricks.c
on ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\xdvipdfmx.cfg"
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
))) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\pst-fp.tex"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\pst-xkey.sty")
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\multido\multido.sty
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\multido\multido.tex
 v1.42, 2010/05/14 <tvz>))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-plot\pst-plot.tex
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-tools\pst-tools.tex
`PST-tools' v0.09b, 2017/12/03 (hv))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pstricks-add\pstricks-add
.tex
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-node\pst-node.tex
 v1.41, 2017/12/30)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-arrow\pst-arrow.tex
`pst-arrow' v0.01, 2016/09/01 (dr,hv))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-3d\pst-3d.tex
`PST-3d' v1.11, 2010/02/14 (tvz))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-math\pst-math.tex
`pst-math' v0.63 , (CJ,hv)) `pstricks-add' v3.85a, 2018/02/03 (dr,hv))
 v1.90, 2018/03/28 (tvz,hv)))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\auto-pst-pdf\auto-pst-pdf.s
ty ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty")
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\ifplatform\ifplatform.sty
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\catchfile.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"))

Package ifplatform Warning: 
    shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

) (C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pst-pdf\pst-pdf.sty
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg")))))
(pst-poker.sty
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pst-blur\pst-blur.sty
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-blur\pst-blur.tex
 v2.0, 2005/09/08))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pst-fill\pst-fill.sty
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-fill\pst-fill.tex
`PST-Fill' v1.01, 2007/03/10 (tvz,dg,hv)))) (make2.aux)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\txfonts\utxsyc.fd) [1miktex-dvipdfmx: warning: running with administrator privileges
]
[2] [3] (make2.aux) )
Output written on make2.pdf (3 pages).
SyncTeX written on make2.synctex.
Transcript written on make2.log.


_____________________________________________________________________

 XeLaTeX Compilation Report (Pages: 3)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 1   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

And **log** file

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (MiKTeX 2.9.6745 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2018.7.21)  21 JUL 2018 20:56
entering extended mode
**./make2.tex
(make2.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"
File: size12.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pst-plot\pst-plot.sty
Package: pst-plot 2011/06/05 v1.00 LaTeX wrapper for `pst-plot' (HV)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pstricks\pstricks.sty"
Package: pstricks 2018/01/06 v0.67 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)

(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\iftex\iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2013/04/04 v0.2 Provides if(tex) conditional for PDFTeX, XeTeX, 
and LuaTeX
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\shellesc.sty"
Package: shellesc 2016/06/07 v0.02a unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
Package shellesc Info: Restricted shell escape enabled on input line 69.
)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\xcolor\xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 225.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-def\xetex.def"
File: xetex.def 2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1348.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1364.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1367.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\pst-xkey.tex"
File: pst-xkey.tex 2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\xkeyval.sty"
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkeyval.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\xkvutils.tex"
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\xkeyval\keyval.tex"))
\XKV@depth=\count88
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\pstricks.tex"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\pst-fp.tex"
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv)
\pstFP@xs=\count89
\pstFP@xia=\count90
\pstFP@xib=\count91
\pstFP@xfa=\count92
\pstFP@xfb=\count93
\pstFP@rega=\count94
\pstFP@regb=\count95
\pstFP@regs=\count96
\pstFP@times=\count97
)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-com
mon.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks16
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen103
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen104

(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfutil-com
mon-lists.tex))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeys.cod
e.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks17
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks18

(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgfkeysfilt
ered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks19
))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\utilities\pgffor.code
.tex
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmath.code.tex

(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathcalc.code
.tex
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathutil.code
.tex
\pgf@x=\dimen105
\pgf@xa=\dimen106
\pgf@xb=\dimen107
\pgf@xc=\dimen108
\pgf@y=\dimen109
\pgf@ya=\dimen110
\pgf@yb=\dimen111
\pgf@yc=\dimen112
\c@pgf@counta=\count98
\c@pgf@countb=\count99
\c@pgf@countc=\count100
\c@pgf@countd=\count101
\pgfutil@tempcnta=\count102
\pgfutil@tempcntb=\count103
)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathparser.co
de.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen113
\pgfmath@count=\count104
\pgfmath@box=\box26
\pgfmath@toks=\toks20
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks21
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks22
)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.code.tex
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.basic.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.trigonometric.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.random.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.comparison.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.base.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.round.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.misc.code.tex)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfunctions
.integerarithmetics.code.tex)))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pgf\math\pgfmathfloat.cod
e.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count105
))
\pgffor@iter=\dimen114
\pgffor@skip=\dimen115
\pgffor@stack=\toks23
\pgffor@toks=\toks24
)
\psLoopIndex=\count106

`PSTricks' v2.84  <2018/05/01> (tvz,hv)
\pst@dima=\dimen116
\pst@dimb=\dimen117
\pst@dimc=\dimen118
\pst@dimd=\dimen119
\pst@dimg=\dimen120
\pst@dimh=\dimen121
\pst@dimm=\dimen122
\pst@dimn=\dimen123
\pst@dimo=\dimen124
\pst@dimp=\dimen125
\pst@hbox=\box27
\pst@ibox=\box28
\pst@boxg=\box29
\pst@cnta=\count107
\pst@cntb=\count108
\pst@cntc=\count109
\pst@cntd=\count110
\pst@cntg=\count111
\pst@cnth=\count112
\pst@cntm=\count113
\pst@cntn=\count114
\pst@cnto=\count115
\pst@cntp=\count116
\@zero=\count117
\pst@toks=\toks25

(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-pstricks\pstricks.c
on ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\xdvipdfmx.cfg"))
\psunit=\dimen126
\psxunit=\dimen127
\psyunit=\dimen128
\pst@C@@rType=\count118
\pslinewidth=\dimen129
\psk@startLW=\dimen130
\psk@endLW=\dimen131
\pst@customdefs=\toks26
\pslinearc=\dimen132
\pst@symbolStep=\dimen133
\pst@symbolWidth=\dimen134
\pst@symbolLinewidth=\dimen135
\everypsbox=\toks27
\psframesep=\dimen136
\pslabelsep=\dimen137
\sh@wgridXunit=\dimen138
\sh@wgridYunit=\dimen139
\pst@shift=\dimen140

(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-pstricks\pstricks.c
on ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\xdvipdfmx.cfg"
Using PSTricks configuration for XeTeX+xdvipdfmx
)))
File: pstricks.tex 2018/05/01 v2.84 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\pstricks\pst-fp.tex")
File: pst-fp.tex 2018/05/01 v2.84 `PST-fp' (hv)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\xkeyval\pst-xkey.sty"
Package: pst-xkey 2005/11/25 v1.6 package wrapper for pst-xkey.tex (HA)
)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\multido\multido.sty
Package: multido 2004/05/17 package wrapper for PSTricks `multido.tex', (HV/RN)


(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\multido\multido.tex
 v1.42, 2010/05/14 <tvz>
\multido@count=\count119
\multidocount=\count120
\multido@stuff=\toks28
)
File: multido.tex 2010/05/14 v1.42 `multido' (tvz,hv)
)
Package: pst-plot 2011/04/13 package wrapper for pst-plot.tex (hv)

(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-plot\pst-plot.tex
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-tools\pst-tools.tex
`PST-tools' v0.09b, 2017/12/03 (hv))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pstricks-add\pstricks-add
.tex
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-node\pst-node.tex
 v1.41, 2017/12/30
\psrow=\count121
\pscol=\count122
\psmatrixcnt=\count123
\psrowsep=\skip43
\pscolsep=\skip44
\pst@args=\count124
\num@pts=\count125
\pst@argcnt=\count126
)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-arrow\pst-arrow.tex
`pst-arrow' v0.01, 2016/09/01 (dr,hv)
\pshooklength=\dimen141
\pshookwidth=\dimen142
)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-3d\pst-3d.tex
`PST-3d' v1.11, 2010/02/14 (tvz))
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-math\pst-math.tex
`pst-math' v0.63 , (CJ,hv)) `pstricks-add' v3.85a, 2018/02/03 (dr,hv)
\psparallelogramsep=\dimen143
\pst@cntC=\count127
\pst@stepcount=\count128
\chart@ColorIndex=\dimen144
\chart@ColorStep=\dimen145
\pst@chartHeight=\dimen146
\pst@chartStackDepth=\dimen147
\pst@chartStackWidth=\dimen148
\chart@Toggle=\count129
\psVectorCtr=\count130
)
 v1.90, 2018/03/28 (tvz,hv)
\pstRadUnit=\dimen149
\pstRadUnitInv=\dimen150
\pst@linecnt=\count131
\RCD@file=\read1
\psxlabelsep=\dimen151
\psylabelsep=\dimen152
\psk@subticksize=\dimen153
\pst@xticksizeA=\dimen154
\pst@xticksizeB=\dimen155
\pst@xticksizeC=\dimen156
\pst@yticksizeA=\dimen157
\pst@yticksizeB=\dimen158
\pst@yticksizeC=\dimen159
\@digitcounter=\count132
\psk@llx=\dimen160
\psk@lly=\dimen161
\psk@urx=\dimen162
\psk@ury=\dimen163
\pst@xunit=\dimen164
\pst@yunit=\dimen165
)
File: pst-plot.tex 2018/03/28 1.90 `pst-plot' (tvz,hv)
)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\auto-pst-pdf\auto-pst-pdf.s
ty
Package: auto-pst-pdf 2009/04/26 v0.6 Wrapper for pst-pdf
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifpdf.sty"
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\ifplatform\ifplatform.sty
Package: ifplatform 2017/10/13 v0.4a Testing for the operating system

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\pdftexcmds.sty"
Package: pdftexcmds 2018/01/30 v0.27 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty"
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifluatex.sty"
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: pdfTeX >= 1.30 not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\catchfile.sty"
Package: catchfile 2016/05/16 v1.7 Catch the contents of a file (HO)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\etexcmds.sty"
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
))

Package ifplatform Warning: 
    shell escape is disabled, so I can only detect \ifwindows.

)
\c@app@runs=\count133
 (C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pst-pdf\pst-pdf.sty
Package: pst-pdf 2017/06/22 v1.2d PS graphics for pdfLaTeX (RN,HjG)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty"
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ifvtex.sty"
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
\c@pspicture=\count134

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics-cfg\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 99.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen166
\Gin@req@width=\dimen167
)
Package pst-pdf Info: MODE: 9 (inactive mode) on input line 459.
))
(pst-poker.sty
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pst-blur\pst-blur.sty
Package: pst-blur 2005/09/08 package wrapper for pst-blur.tex (hv)

(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-blur\pst-blur.tex
 v2.0, 2005/09/08)
File: pst-blur.tex 2005/09/08 v2.0 `PST-blur' (hv)
)
(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\pst-fill\pst-fill.sty
Package: pst-fill 2005/09/13 package wrapper for pst-fill.tex (hv)

(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\generic\pst-fill\pst-fill.tex
`PST-Fill' v1.01, 2007/03/10 (tvz,dg,hv)
\pst@fillbox=\box30
)
File: pst-fill.tex 2007/03/10 v1.01 `PST-fill' (tvz,dg)
)
File: pst-poker 2017/08/23\ v0.02\ [LaTeX poker package (HV)
\symsymbolsC=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `symbolsC' in version `bold'
(Font)                  U/txsyc/m/n --> U/txsyc/bx/n on input line 146.
) (make2.aux)
\openout1 = `make2.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 18.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 27.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+txsyc on input line 27.

(C:\Users\cy.i\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\txfonts\utxsyc.fd
File: utxsyc.fd 2000/12/15 v3.1
)
File: King-diamond-color.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<King-diamond-color.eps>
File: Queen-diamond-color.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<Queen-diamond-color.eps>
File: Jack-diamond-color.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<Jack-diamond-color.eps>
File: Jack-club-color.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<Jack-club-color.eps>
File: Jack-club-color.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<Jack-club-color.eps>
File: Jack-heart-color.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<Jack-heart-color.eps>
File: Jack-spade-color.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<Jack-spade-color.eps>
File: Jack-diamond-color.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<Jack-diamond-color.eps>
 [1

]
File: Jack-spade-color.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<Jack-spade-color.eps>
File: King-spade-color.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<King-spade-color.eps>
File: Queen-spade-color.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<Queen-spade-color.eps>

[2]
File: Jack-spade-color.eps Graphic file (type eps)
<Jack-spade-color.eps>
 [3] (make2.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 10509 strings out of 427798
 181825 string characters out of 3151797
 389514 words of memory out of 3000000
 14342 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 7149 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1328 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 43i,5n,51p,644b,426s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on make2.pdf (3 pages).
```

Comment: @samcarter Damn, `poker` seems to be only compiler-able with this crap...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You already load `auto-pst-pdf` which is not needed by `xelatex`. But you can run it with `pdflatex` if you use the `postscript` environment. For example:

```
\section{Full house}
Three of a kind with a pair.
\begin{center}
\begin{postscript}
    \crdtens
    \crdtenh
    \crdtend
    \crdnines
    \crdnined
\end{postscript}
\end{center}
```

Then `pdflatex`  needs only a few seconds

Comment: I also read somewhere about `--enable-write18`.  All kinds of work-around, wasted hours ...

Comment: I think this igores `\cleardoublepage` but much much faster, which I can live with!! Thanks!

Comment: you can use `...\end{postscript} \cleardoublepage \begin{postscript}...`

Comment: Tried already. When combined with `\usepackage{comicsans}` all kinds of weird things happen. Without `\usepackage{comicsans}`, the `...\end{postscript} \cleardoublepage \begin{postscript}...` works fine.

Comment: For OpenType fonts use `usepackage{auto-pst-pdf-lua}` and run `lualatex`

Comment: Thanks again. This is just too much change from my "normal" routine compilation. Also, it does not seem to work on `https://www.sharelatex.com/`, which is a shame.

Answer (score 2):

Run `fc-cache` in console. This will help the system find the fonts.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please provide some more information.